# How to convert 'creation_time' & 'last_modified_time' format columns from metatables in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I runned the query :

SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`

to get a summary of all my tables from a specific dataset.

My problem is about the format of the columns "creation_time" and "last_modified_time". It shows me dates in the format of a sequence of 13 digits.

Is there a way to convert it to common date format ?

( I expected a format like YYYY-mm-dd )

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field contains milliseconds since epoch. You can use

```sql
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time
```

to get a proper timestamp.

I'm using something like

```sql
SELECT
  * REPLACE(
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time
  ),
  size_bytes/pow(1024,3) size_gigaBytes
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
```